# How to set an android's view accessibility flag of "button" to "true"?

Tags: android, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I have a ConstraintLayout with an onClickListener so users can tap anywhere on the layout for it to perform its onClickListener action.

The problem is, Android does not flag this item as a button. It will say "double tap to activate" but our accessibility team has flagged this as incorrect because screen-reader users need to know the item is a "button" (from the Android tag) to know an item is actionable.

In the past, my work-around was to change views to be a button that looks exactly alike. However, this is a lot more difficult in this case because it's a ConstraintView.

Does anyone know how to set Accessibility's 'button' flag to 'true' on a ConstraintView? Or on any view?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need a ConstraintLayout ?

Comment: I used constraintLayout so the entire row is selectable. There are multiple rows containing areas that the user can select, each constraint layout contains multiple views.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix worked like a charm:

```
fun View.setAccessibilityRole(role: String = "button") {
    ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(this, object :
        AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
            info.roleDescription = role
            info.className = role
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer would seem to work, the main issue would be that you are then relying on your app's translation team to translate "button" if the screen reader user uses any language that doesn't have the same word for button.

```
    // example usage
    // val view = findViewById(...)
    // view.setAccessibilityRole<Button>()

    inline fun <reified T: View> View.setAccessibilityRole() {
        ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(
            this,
            object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
                override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
                    host: View,
                    info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat
                ) {
                    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
                    info.className = T::class.qualifiedName
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

This works for a button, and probably other standard controls like `RatingBar`, `ProgressBar` and `CheckBox` but could probably be refined to be a little safer than what I have done.

A word of caution: There be dragons here. It can walk like a button, talk like a button, but there might be elements that go against the grain that make it inaccessible further and lead you to more regressions, as can be seen by the other answer (translation issue). Other examples are keyboard navigation and highlight, or touch target size, or someone doesn't load text / content description and then wonders why it's not focusable by a screen reader, switch access or voice assistant. You could also end up with focusable controls *within* your "button" and that could be terribly confusing for certain users, depending on how they use the device (TalkBack does not encompass all assistive tech).

You're always better off extending existing controls for this reason.